# Android App connected to Rhode microphone as well as Bluetooth speaker

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a android mobile **(Moto g 2nd generation)**, portable Bluetooth speaker with Inbuilt MIC, Rhode smart Lav+ microphone compatible with.

Both the **mic and blue tooth** speaker are connected to my mobile. Now I want to route the audio from the **mic to the blue tooth speaker.**

Can any one suggest how to achieve the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed he below app.

[MIC to SPEAKER](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ad960009.app.MicToSpeaker&hl=en)

It is working as expected but the problem is there is a slight delay of 2 seconds.